# Graphing Gaussian Process in R using rstan

Tags: r, bayesian, data-visualization, rstan

I am trying to understand where I am going wrong with `rstan`. I have figured out a workaround, but it seems like there should be a better option for graphing draws from the posterior than what I have come up with.

I am trying to learn how to use `rstan` for modeling a Gaussian process related to another question I have open on [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323433/guassian-process-for-data-imputation) (shameless plug but if you have ideas that can help out there I am all ears).

I figured as a first step I would try going through the [stan documentation](http://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/index.html) examples of a Gaussian process. So I built a model simply designed to draw random squared exponential covariance functions.

```
library(rstan)
library(rstanarm)
library(bayesplot)
library(ggplot2)
options(mc.cores=parallel::detectCores())
rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)

x<-seq(0, 30, by=.01)

model<-'
data{
    int<lower=1> N;
    real x[N];
  }

transformed data {
  matrix[N, N] L;
  matrix[N, N] K;
  vector[N] mu = rep_vector(0, N);
  for (i in 1:(N - 1)) {
    K[i, i] = 1 + 0.1;
    for (j in (i + 1):N) {
      K[i, j] = exp(-0.5 * square(x[i] - x[j]));
      K[j, i] = K[i, j];
    }
  }
  K[N, N] = 1 + 0.1;
  L = cholesky_decompose(K);
}

parameters {
  vector[N] eta;
}

model {
  eta ~ normal(0, 1);
}
generated quantities {
  vector[N] y;
  y = mu + L*eta;
}
'
```

I followed the documentation's suggestion of including a Cholesky decomposition on transformed data.

Using `stan` I fit the model as follows:

```
dat<-list(N=length(x),
          x=x)

fit <- stan(model_code = model,
            data = dat, 
            iter = 1000, 
            chains = 1, 
            pars = c('y', 'eta'),
            control = list(adapt_delta=.99, 
                           max_treedepth=10)
            )
```

I can visualize the posterior distributions of each of my draws using the following code:

```
posterior<-as.matrix(fit)
mcmc_areas(posterior, 
           pars=c('y[1]', 'y[2]'),
           prob = .90
           )
```

Which produces:

[image]

I really want to look at the results of each process (not all 500 but some random draws thereof).

I tried multiple alternative strategies and eventually landed on the following:

```
post.y<-extract(fit, pars='y')

draws<-sample(1:500, size = 10)

DF<-data.frame(Time=x, y=colMeans(post.y$y), Draw=rep('Mu', length(x)))
for(i in 1:length(draws)){
  DF.temp<-data.frame(Time=x, y=post.y$y[i,], Draw=rep(paste0('posterior', i), length(x)))
  DF<-rbind(DF, DF.temp)
}

g1<-ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=y), data=DF)
g2<-g1+geom_line(aes(x=Time, y=y, group=Draw, color=Draw), data=DF[DF$Draw!='Mu',], alpha=.25, show.legend = F)
g3<-g2+geom_line(aes(x=Time, y=y), data=DF[DF$Draw=='Mu',], lwd=1.5)
g3
```

And this code produces:
[image]

This seems like a lot of extra hoops to jump through. I tried alternative approaches using other functions in the `rstan` family (e.g., `ppc_dens_overlay`), but they all resulted in errors or did not return what I wanted.

So my question here is really about alternative, simpler options I can use to visualize the overall average of my draws for each value of $y_i$ as well as the overall mean of all draws for each value (which should be 0 in this case but may not in other cases when data changes over time in a structure way).

I am relatively new to `rstan` (have used `rbugs` and `rjags`) so I may be simply unaware of some simple set of functions that can make this process easier.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Here's a tutorial from a stan developer on gaussian processes that includes some plots: http://mc-stan.org/events/stancon2017-notebooks/stancon2017-trangucci-hierarchical-gps.pdf. It seems like the hoops are necessary right now to plot gaussian processes in stan.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll take a look. My concern, of course, is really not with a simple model like this but what is going to happen when I scale to something much more complex in nature with multiple covariance functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could reproduce your second figure with a bit less code using `matplot`, which conveniently works with matrix data.

```
post.y <- rstan::extract(fit, 'y')$y
post.y.sub <- post.y[sample(1:nrow(post.y), 10),]

matplot(x, t(post.y.sub), type = 'l', lty = 1, col = adjustcolor(palette(), 0.25))
lines(colMeans(post.y) ~ x, lwd = 2)
```

If you prefer ggplot2, the hard part is getting the posterior samples into a data frame. I find the `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries helpful here. It looks like a lot of code, but it's flexible when your models get more complicated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df.rep <- post.y %>% 
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(x = x) %>% 
  gather(rep, post.y, -x)

df.mean <- df.rep %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarize(mu = mean(post.y))

df.rep.sub <- df.rep %>% 
  filter(rep %in% sample(unique(rep), 10))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df.rep.sub, aes(x, post.y, col = rep), alpha = 0.25, show.legend = F) +
  geom_line(data = df.mean, aes(x, mu), lwd = 1.5)
```